# how do I upgrade centos 6 to centos 7

Tags: centos6, centos7, upgrade

How do I upgrade a CentOS6.9 virtual machine to CentOS7?
I tried doing a yum -y update but that did not do it for me.

I would appreciate if anyone could share a procedure with me.

Answer (score 4):

Really simple answer would be: you don't.

There is a [tool](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool) for this purpose, but it's at a broken state right now.

Your only choice is to backup your data, install 7 from scratch and put your data back.

There has been significant changes going to 7, so as far as I know, it was never meant to be simply upgraded from 6.

Also, yum update is only meant to upgrade according to repo within that OS version, not to upgrade OS itself.